# CentOS 5.10 can't enable php-openssl extension

Tags: php, linux, openssl, centos, php-openssl

I have installed CentOS 5.10 on my server and PHP 5.4.17, but the problem is that I can't enable php-openssl extension. By the command 'locate openssl' looks like the extension exists, so I tried to create the openssl.ini file in '/etc/php.d/' but there nothing happens.

Output by `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep -i openssl`:

> OpenSSL support => disabled (install ext/openssl)

How I can enable that ext? I tried search in google, but found nothing useful. Sorry for my english. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You enable it by making sure that the relevant files are installed on your server - you will need openSSL and the PHP openSSL extension (on a nearby RHEL 5.1 box, openSSL support is built in - it seems a little strange the Centos 5.10 should be any different).

If, as apparently in your case it is implemented as an external module, then you'll also need to amend your php.ini to load the extension. The convention with redhat is that optional extensions have their own file in /etc/php.d

Looking at the [rpm list for Centos](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.10/os/i386/CentOS/) though, they don't seem to have openssl in a seperate extension. Could you have a non-standard binary?

Perhaps someone with Centos 5.10 can advise if it's linked at compile time (in which case you must have a modified binary)?